# SIGABRT when trying to access array values in JNI

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface

im currently trying to integrate a c library to my android project.
The extern function accepts a `Array<Double>` for example

```
val doubleArray= arrayOf(0.0)
MyClass().myFunction(doubleArray)
```

in the native part of the application, im trying to access it like this:

```
Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_myFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jdoubleArray myArray) {
jdouble *body_ = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, myArray, 0);
}
```

This is the way, how the documentation tells me to access my array values. But when im doing this, i'm getting a SIGABRT.

What am i missing here? Would appreciate when you can point me the direction :)

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? What does the stacktrace look like?

Answer (score 0):

An `Array<Double>` is a `java.lang.Double[]` in JVM terms, ie an array of objects.

You meant to create a [`DoubleArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double-array/), which is a `double[]` (the primitive).

Comment: unfortunately, it doesnt make a difference if i use Array<Double> or DoubleArray. Still the same issue.

Comment: Where do you Release the array again? The JVM cannot do anything as long as that mapping is held.

Comment: i left out this part  in the example, but im doing this afterwards.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Run with `-Xcheck:jni` and/or attach a debugger?